# Common Errors For Low R Value in Bradford Assay

Tags: molecular-biology, lab-techniques

I've recently started doing Bradford Assays for my samples and my standard curve has been non-linear and I have been getting low R values (.90-.95). I initially thought the error was in pipetting, most likely in adding BSA while establishing the standards but I have repeated in care and somehow still get low R values. Are there any other possible sources of error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You could be measuring outside the dynamic range of the assay (you can only add so much / so little BSA to a certain amount of reagent).
- You could be outside the linear range of your spectrophotometer, usually under 1 is fine, although some old/crappy ones might not even be reliable over 0.5.
- If you're fast you're measuring your different concentrations also at different times. Bradford is a little bit time-dependent, so waiting the recommended time before measuring your standards is not a bad idea.

Probably it's still pipetting though, try pipetting at least 20 uL in every dilution step and see if you're still off.